# subtracting every entry of a column with first value of the column

Tags: python

I had a file which has 2 columns like:

```
13.245 cat
14.323 dog
16.246 pig
```

I want to subtract each entry of first column with first column value of first row(here it is 13.245) and write the result to another file with modified values so that the output file looks:

```
0.000 cat
1.078 dog
3.001 pig
```

I had a very crude solution. I stored the value 13.245 in a variable and i split each line, subtract 13.245 value from split()[0] entry and write that value and split()[1] value to another file seperated by space. I do this line by line. Is there a solution which is not so crude as this. I mean, without storing the first column of first row entry into external variable and then writing entires manually into another file, is there any swift method?

Comment: nope..there are no blank lines in files. they just got pronted like that.sorry

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: In the end you'll have to read and parse each line, do the math, and then write each line. I think it doesn't get any nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one solution:

```
def process_line(line, first_value, outf):
    parts = line.strip().split(' ')
    parts[0] = '%.3f' % (float(parts[0]) - first_value)
    print >>outf, ' '.join(parts)

with open('in.txt') as inf, open('out.txt', 'w') as outf:
    first_line = inf.readline().strip()
    first_value = float(first_line.split(' ', 1)[0])
    process_line(first_line, first_value, outf)
    for line in inf:
        process_line(line, first_value, outf)
```

Comment: @user1411416 you have already made a few questions in stackoverflow and yet, you have not accepted any. If you don't accept useful answers, people may decide not to answer your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = """13.245 cat
14.323 dog
16.246 pig"""
parsed_data = [(float(x[0]), x[1]) for x in [x.split() for x in  data.splitlines()]]
subtract = parsed_data[0][0]
for (num, animal) in parsed_data:
    print "%.3f %s" % (num - subtract, animal)
```

Comment: Thank you - included above now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as infile, open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    first_line = infile.readline().split()
    first_val = float(first_line[0])
    outfile.write("%.3f %s\n" % (0, first_line[1]))

    for line in infile:
        first_col, second_col = line.split()
        outfile.write("%.3f %s\n" % (float(first_col) - first_val, second_col))
```

Comment: @TylerCrompton: Haha yeah I just notice I wrote `int()`. :P

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for something can't be done much more easily. But this is probably the shortest you can make it. Which version of Python, by the way? This is for 3.

```
with open('<file_name>') as input_file, open('<output_file>', 'w') as output_file:
    lines = list(map(lambda line: (float(line[0]), line[1]), map(lambda line: line.split(), input_file)))
    for line in lines:
        print(line[0] - lines[0][0], line[1], file=output_file)
```

Comment: This one is shorter but it loads all the lines into memory. That could be a problem if the file is long.